# Error: Module not declared as a System.registerDynamic dependency of module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I keep trying to call an image location using stored data on firebase it seems to work fine on my other component, however, I keep getting this error on this component when switching to the page on my app, even the console logging of the data works fine. Any help would be great thanks!

```
export class Dog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    await firebase
      .database()
      .ref("pets")
      .on("value", snapshot => {
        this.setState({ data: [].concat.apply([], snapshot.val()) });
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.data.map((obj, index) => {
          console.log(obj.image);
          return (
            <View key={index}>
              <Image source={require(obj.image)} />
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Dog;
```

Comment: Please try clean npm cache and npm install your packages. Also check this link https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/652